# IDA: Why does this function/sub has 4 arguments, and why is one a struct?

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, calling-convention, ida

I'm really (reaaaally) new to IDA (and debugging in general), so I wanted to ask a little for some directions.

I have this sub / function:

```
sub_5AE50B      proc near               ; CODE XREF: sub_4F0E29+252p
.text:005AE50B                                         ; sub_5B81A9+36p
.text:005AE50B
.text:005AE50B var_548         = dword ptr -548h
.text:005AE50B var_544         = dword ptr -544h
.text:005AE50B var_540         = dword ptr -540h
.text:005AE50B var_53C         = dword ptr -53Ch
.text:005AE50B var_538         = dword ptr -538h
.text:005AE50B var_534         = dword ptr -534h
.text:005AE50B var_530         = dword ptr -530h
.text:005AE50B var_52C         = dword ptr -52Ch
.text:005AE50B var_528         = dword ptr -528h
.text:005AE50B var_524         = dword ptr -524h
.text:005AE50B var_520         = dword ptr -520h
.text:005AE50B var_51C         = dword ptr -51Ch
.text:005AE50B var_518         = dword ptr -518h
.text:005AE50B var_514         = dword ptr -514h
.text:005AE50B var_510         = dword ptr -510h
.text:005AE50B var_50C         = dword ptr -50Ch
.text:005AE50B var_508         = dword ptr -508h
.text:005AE50B var_504         = dword ptr -504h
.text:005AE50B var_500         = dword ptr -500h
.text:005AE50B var_4FC         = dword ptr -4FCh
.text:005AE50B var_4F8         = dword ptr -4F8h
.text:005AE50B var_4F4         = dword ptr -4F4h
.text:005AE50B var_4F0         = dword ptr -4F0h
.text:005AE50B var_4EC         = dword ptr -4ECh
.text:005AE50B var_4E8         = dword ptr -4E8h
.text:005AE50B var_4E4         = dword ptr -4E4h
.text:005AE50B var_4E0         = dword ptr -4E0h
.text:005AE50B var_4DC         = dword ptr -4DCh
.text:005AE50B var_4D8         = dword ptr -4D8h
.text:005AE50B var_4D4         = dword ptr -4D4h
.text:005AE50B var_4D0         = dword ptr -4D0h
.text:005AE50B var_4CC         = dword ptr -4CCh
.text:005AE50B var_4C8         = dword ptr -4C8h
.text:005AE50B var_4C4         = dword ptr -4C4h
.text:005AE50B var_4C0         = dword ptr -4C0h
.text:005AE50B var_4BC         = dword ptr -4BCh
.text:005AE50B var_4B8         = dword ptr -4B8h
.text:005AE50B var_4B4         = dword ptr -4B4h
.text:005AE50B var_4B0         = dword ptr -4B0h
.text:005AE50B var_4AC         = dword ptr -4ACh
.text:005AE50B var_4A8         = dword ptr -4A8h
.text:005AE50B var_4A4         = dword ptr -4A4h
.text:005AE50B var_4A0         = byte ptr -4A0h
.text:005AE50B var_49C         = dword ptr -49Ch
.text:005AE50B var_498         = dword ptr -498h
.text:005AE50B var_494         = dword ptr -494h
.text:005AE50B var_490         = dword ptr -490h
.text:005AE50B var_48C         = dword ptr -48Ch
.text:005AE50B var_488         = dword ptr -488h
.text:005AE50B var_484         = dword ptr -484h
.text:005AE50B var_480         = dword ptr -480h
.text:005AE50B var_47C         = dword ptr -47Ch
.text:005AE50B var_478         = dword ptr -478h
.text:005AE50B var_474         = dword ptr -474h
.text:005AE50B var_470         = dword ptr -470h
.text:005AE50B var_46C         = dword ptr -46Ch
.text:005AE50B var_468         = dword ptr -468h
.text:005AE50B var_464         = dword ptr -464h
.text:005AE50B var_460         = dword ptr -460h
.text:005AE50B var_45C         = dword ptr -45Ch
.text:005AE50B var_458         = dword ptr -458h
.text:005AE50B var_454         = dword ptr -454h
.text:005AE50B var_450         = dword ptr -450h
.text:005AE50B var_444         = dword ptr -444h
.text:005AE50B var_440         = dword ptr -440h
.text:005AE50B var_43C         = dword ptr -43Ch
.text:005AE50B var_438         = dword ptr -438h
.text:005AE50B var_434         = dword ptr -434h
.text:005AE50B var_430         = dword ptr -430h
.text:005AE50B var_42C         = dword ptr -42Ch
.text:005AE50B var_428         = dword ptr -428h
.text:005AE50B var_424         = dword ptr -424h
.text:005AE50B var_418         = dword ptr -418h
.text:005AE50B var_414         = dword ptr -414h
.text:005AE50B var_410         = dword ptr -410h
.text:005AE50B var_40C         = dword ptr -40Ch
.text:005AE50B var_408         = dword ptr -408h
.text:005AE50B var_404         = dword ptr -404h
.text:005AE50B var_400         = dword ptr -400h
.text:005AE50B var_3FC         = dword ptr -3FCh
.text:005AE50B var_3F8         = dword ptr -3F8h
.text:005AE50B var_3EC         = dword ptr -3ECh
.text:005AE50B var_3E8         = dword ptr -3E8h
.text:005AE50B var_3E4         = dword ptr -3E4h
.text:005AE50B var_3E0         = dword ptr -3E0h
.text:005AE50B var_3DC         = dword ptr -3DCh
.text:005AE50B var_3D8         = dword ptr -3D8h
.text:005AE50B var_3D4         = dword ptr -3D4h
.text:005AE50B var_3D0         = dword ptr -3D0h
.text:005AE50B var_3CC         = dword ptr -3CCh
.text:005AE50B var_3C8         = dword ptr -3C8h
.text:005AE50B var_3C4         = dword ptr -3C4h
.text:005AE50B var_3C0         = dword ptr -3C0h
.text:005AE50B var_3BC         = dword ptr -3BCh
.text:005AE50B var_3B8         = dword ptr -3B8h
.text:005AE50B var_3AC         = dword ptr -3ACh
.text:005AE50B var_3A8         = dword ptr -3A8h
.text:005AE50B var_3A4         = dword ptr -3A4h
.text:005AE50B var_3A0         = dword ptr -3A0h
.text:005AE50B var_39C         = dword ptr -39Ch
.text:005AE50B var_398         = dword ptr -398h
.text:005AE50B var_394         = dword ptr -394h
.text:005AE50B var_390         = dword ptr -390h
.text:005AE50B var_38C         = dword ptr -38Ch
.text:005AE50B var_380         = dword ptr -380h
.text:005AE50B var_37C         = dword ptr -37Ch
.text:005AE50B var_378         = dword ptr -378h
.text:005AE50B var_374         = dword ptr -374h
.text:005AE50B var_370         = dword ptr -370h
.text:005AE50B var_36C         = dword ptr -36Ch
.text:005AE50B var_368         = dword ptr -368h
.text:005AE50B var_364         = dword ptr -364h
.text:005AE50B var_360         = dword ptr -360h
.text:005AE50B var_35C         = dword ptr -35Ch
.text:005AE50B var_358         = dword ptr -358h
.text:005AE50B var_354         = dword ptr -354h
.text:005AE50B var_350         = dword ptr -350h
.text:005AE50B var_34C         = dword ptr -34Ch
.text:005AE50B var_348         = dword ptr -348h
.text:005AE50B var_344         = dword ptr -344h
.text:005AE50B var_340         = dword ptr -340h
.text:005AE50B var_33C         = dword ptr -33Ch
.text:005AE50B var_338         = dword ptr -338h
.text:005AE50B var_334         = dword ptr -334h
.text:005AE50B var_330         = dword ptr -330h
.text:005AE50B var_32C         = dword ptr -32Ch
.text:005AE50B var_328         = dword ptr -328h
.text:005AE50B var_324         = dword ptr -324h
.text:005AE50B var_320         = dword ptr -320h
.text:005AE50B var_31C         = dword ptr -31Ch
.text:005AE50B var_318         = dword ptr -318h
.text:005AE50B var_314         = dword ptr -314h
.text:005AE50B var_310         = dword ptr -310h
.text:005AE50B var_30C         = dword ptr -30Ch
.text:005AE50B var_308         = dword ptr -308h
.text:005AE50B var_304         = dword ptr -304h
.text:005AE50B v               = dword ptr -2FCh
.text:005AE50B var_2F8         = dword ptr -2F8h
.text:005AE50B var_2F4         = dword ptr -2F4h
.text:005AE50B var_2F0         = dword ptr -2F0h
.text:005AE50B var_2EC         = dword ptr -2ECh
.text:005AE50B var_2E8         = dword ptr -2E8h
.text:005AE50B var_2E4         = dword ptr -2E4h
.text:005AE50B var_2E0         = dword ptr -2E0h
.text:005AE50B var_2DC         = dword ptr -2DCh
.text:005AE50B var_2D8         = dword ptr -2D8h
.text:005AE50B var_2D4         = dword ptr -2D4h
.text:005AE50B var_2D0         = dword ptr -2D0h
.text:005AE50B var_2CC         = dword ptr -2CCh
.text:005AE50B var_2C8         = dword ptr -2C8h
.text:005AE50B var_2C4         = dword ptr -2C4h
.text:005AE50B var_2C0         = dword ptr -2C0h
.text:005AE50B var_2BC         = dword ptr -2BCh
.text:005AE50B var_2B8         = dword ptr -2B8h
.text:005AE50B var_2B4         = dword ptr -2B4h
.text:005AE50B var_2B0         = dword ptr -2B0h
.text:005AE50B var_2AC         = dword ptr -2ACh
.text:005AE50B var_2A8         = dword ptr -2A8h
.text:005AE50B var_2A4         = dword ptr -2A4h
.text:005AE50B var_298         = dword ptr -298h
.text:005AE50B var_294         = dword ptr -294h
.text:005AE50B var_290         = dword ptr -290h
.text:005AE50B var_28C         = dword ptr -28Ch
.text:005AE50B var_288         = dword ptr -288h
.text:005AE50B var_284         = dword ptr -284h
.text:005AE50B var_280         = dword ptr -280h
.text:005AE50B var_274         = dword ptr -274h
.text:005AE50B var_270         = dword ptr -270h
.text:005AE50B var_26C         = dword ptr -26Ch
.text:005AE50B var_268         = dword ptr -268h
.text:005AE50B var_264         = dword ptr -264h
.text:005AE50B var_260         = dword ptr -260h
.text:005AE50B var_25C         = dword ptr -25Ch
.text:005AE50B var_250         = dword ptr -250h
.text:005AE50B var_24C         = dword ptr -24Ch
.text:005AE50B var_248         = dword ptr -248h
.text:005AE50B var_244         = dword ptr -244h
.text:005AE50B var_240         = dword ptr -240h
.text:005AE50B var_23C         = dword ptr -23Ch
.text:005AE50B var_238         = dword ptr -238h
.text:005AE50B var_22C         = dword ptr -22Ch
.text:005AE50B var_228         = dword ptr -228h
.text:005AE50B var_224         = dword ptr -224h
.text:005AE50B var_220         = dword ptr -220h
.text:005AE50B var_21C         = dword ptr -21Ch
.text:005AE50B var_218         = dword ptr -218h
.text:005AE50B var_214         = dword ptr -214h
.text:005AE50B var_210         = dword ptr -210h
.text:005AE50B var_20C         = dword ptr -20Ch
.text:005AE50B var_208         = dword ptr -208h
.text:005AE50B var_204         = dword ptr -204h
.text:005AE50B var_200         = dword ptr -200h
.text:005AE50B var_1FC         = dword ptr -1FCh
.text:005AE50B var_1F0         = dword ptr -1F0h
.text:005AE50B var_1EC         = dword ptr -1ECh
.text:005AE50B var_1E8         = dword ptr -1E8h
.text:005AE50B var_1E4         = dword ptr -1E4h
.text:005AE50B var_1E0         = dword ptr -1E0h
.text:005AE50B var_1DC         = dword ptr -1DCh
.text:005AE50B var_1D8         = dword ptr -1D8h
.text:005AE50B var_1CC         = dword ptr -1CCh
.text:005AE50B var_1C8         = dword ptr -1C8h
.text:005AE50B var_1C4         = dword ptr -1C4h
.text:005AE50B var_1C0         = dword ptr -1C0h
.text:005AE50B var_1BC         = dword ptr -1BCh
.text:005AE50B var_1B0         = dword ptr -1B0h
.text:005AE50B var_1AC         = dword ptr -1ACh
.text:005AE50B var_1A8         = dword ptr -1A8h
.text:005AE50B var_1A4         = dword ptr -1A4h
.text:005AE50B var_1A0         = dword ptr -1A0h
.text:005AE50B var_19C         = dword ptr -19Ch
.text:005AE50B var_198         = dword ptr -198h
.text:005AE50B var_194         = dword ptr -194h
.text:005AE50B var_190         = dword ptr -190h
.text:005AE50B var_184         = dword ptr -184h
.text:005AE50B var_180         = dword ptr -180h
.text:005AE50B var_17C         = dword ptr -17Ch
.text:005AE50B var_178         = dword ptr -178h
.text:005AE50B var_174         = dword ptr -174h
.text:005AE50B var_170         = dword ptr -170h
.text:005AE50B var_16C         = dword ptr -16Ch
.text:005AE50B var_168         = dword ptr -168h
.text:005AE50B var_164         = dword ptr -164h
.text:005AE50B var_160         = dword ptr -160h
.text:005AE50B var_154         = dword ptr -154h
.text:005AE50B var_150         = dword ptr -150h
.text:005AE50B var_14C         = dword ptr -14Ch
.text:005AE50B var_148         = dword ptr -148h
.text:005AE50B var_144         = dword ptr -144h
.text:005AE50B var_140         = dword ptr -140h
.text:005AE50B var_13C         = dword ptr -13Ch
.text:005AE50B var_138         = dword ptr -138h
.text:005AE50B var_134         = dword ptr -134h
.text:005AE50B var_130         = dword ptr -130h
.text:005AE50B var_12C         = dword ptr -12Ch
.text:005AE50B var_128         = dword ptr -128h
.text:005AE50B var_124         = dword ptr -124h
.text:005AE50B var_120         = dword ptr -120h
.text:005AE50B var_11C         = dword ptr -11Ch
.text:005AE50B var_118         = dword ptr -118h
.text:005AE50B var_114         = dword ptr -114h
.text:005AE50B var_110         = dword ptr -110h
.text:005AE50B var_10C         = dword ptr -10Ch
.text:005AE50B var_108         = dword ptr -108h
.text:005AE50B var_104         = dword ptr -104h
.text:005AE50B var_100         = dword ptr -100h
.text:005AE50B var_FC          = dword ptr -0FCh
.text:005AE50B var_F8          = dword ptr -0F8h
.text:005AE50B var_F4          = dword ptr -0F4h
.text:005AE50B var_F0          = dword ptr -0F0h
.text:005AE50B var_EC          = dword ptr -0ECh
.text:005AE50B var_E8          = dword ptr -0E8h
.text:005AE50B var_E4          = dword ptr -0E4h
.text:005AE50B var_E0          = dword ptr -0E0h
.text:005AE50B var_DC          = dword ptr -0DCh
.text:005AE50B var_D8          = dword ptr -0D8h
.text:005AE50B var_D4          = dword ptr -0D4h
.text:005AE50B var_D0          = dword ptr -0D0h
.text:005AE50B var_CC          = dword ptr -0CCh
.text:005AE50B var_C8          = dword ptr -0C8h
.text:005AE50B var_C4          = dword ptr -0C4h
.text:005AE50B var_C0          = dword ptr -0C0h
.text:005AE50B var_BC          = dword ptr -0BCh
.text:005AE50B var_B8          = dword ptr -0B8h
.text:005AE50B var_B4          = dword ptr -0B4h
.text:005AE50B var_B0          = dword ptr -0B0h
.text:005AE50B var_AC          = dword ptr -0ACh
.text:005AE50B var_A8          = dword ptr -0A8h
.text:005AE50B var_A4          = dword ptr -0A4h
.text:005AE50B var_A0          = dword ptr -0A0h
.text:005AE50B var_9C          = dword ptr -9Ch
.text:005AE50B var_98          = dword ptr -98h
.text:005AE50B var_94          = dword ptr -94h
.text:005AE50B var_90          = dword ptr -90h
.text:005AE50B var_84          = dword ptr -84h
.text:005AE50B var_80          = dword ptr -80h
.text:005AE50B var_7C          = dword ptr -7Ch
.text:005AE50B var_78          = dword ptr -78h
.text:005AE50B var_74          = dword ptr -74h
.text:005AE50B var_70          = dword ptr -70h
.text:005AE50B var_6C          = dword ptr -6Ch
.text:005AE50B var_68          = dword ptr -68h
.text:005AE50B var_64          = dword ptr -64h
.text:005AE50B var_60          = dword ptr -60h
.text:005AE50B var_5C          = dword ptr -5Ch
.text:005AE50B var_58          = dword ptr -58h
.text:005AE50B var_54          = dword ptr -54h
.text:005AE50B var_50          = dword ptr -50h
.text:005AE50B var_4C          = dword ptr -4Ch
.text:005AE50B var_48          = dword ptr -48h
.text:005AE50B var_44          = dword ptr -44h
.text:005AE50B var_40          = dword ptr -40h
.text:005AE50B var_3C          = dword ptr -3Ch
.text:005AE50B var_38          = dword ptr -38h
.text:005AE50B var_34          = dword ptr -34h
.text:005AE50B var_30          = dword ptr -30h
.text:005AE50B var_2C          = dword ptr -2Ch
.text:005AE50B var_28          = dword ptr -28h
.text:005AE50B var_24          = dword ptr -24h
.text:005AE50B var_20          = dword ptr -20h
.text:005AE50B var_1C          = dword ptr -1Ch
.text:005AE50B alpha           = dword ptr -18h
.text:005AE50B var_14          = dword ptr -14h
.text:005AE50B var_10          = dword ptr -10h
.text:005AE50B var_C           = dword ptr -0Ch
.text:005AE50B var_4           = dword ptr -4
.text:005AE50B arg_0           = dword ptr  8
.text:005AE50B arg_C           = dword ptr  14h
.text:005AE50B
.text:005AE50B                 push    ebp
.text:005AE50C                 mov     ebp, esp
.text:005AE50E                 push    0FFFFFFFFh
.text:005AE510                 push    offset loc_876BAE
.text:005AE515                 mov     eax, large fs:0
.text:005AE51B                 push    eax
.text:005AE51C                 mov     large fs:0, esp
.text:005AE523                 sub     esp, 524h
.text:005AE529                 mov     eax, [ebp+arg_0]
.text:005AE52C                 mov     ecx, [eax+30h]
.text:005AE52F                 imul    ecx, 0F4h
.text:005AE535                 mov     edx, dword_596CB28
.text:005AE53B                 add     edx, ecx
.text:005AE53D                 mov     [ebp+var_10], edx
.text:005AE540                 mov     byte ptr [ebp+var_14], 1
.text:005AE544                 cmp     dword_7B46AF4, 0
.text:005AE54B                 jnz     short loc_5AE567
.text:005AE54D                 cmp     dword_7B46AF4, 0
.text:005AE554                 jnz     loc_5B817B
.text:005AE55A                 mov     eax, [ebp+arg_0]
.text:005AE55D                 cmp     dword ptr [eax+3Ch], 0FFFFFFFEh
.text:005AE561                 jz      loc_5B817B
.text:005AE567
.text:005AE567 loc_5AE567:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_5AE50B+40j
.text:005AE567                 cmp     [ebp+arg_C], 0Ah
.text:005AE56B                 jnz     loc_5AE7C9
.text:005AE571                 mov     [ebp+alpha], 3F000000h
.text:005AE578                 mov     [ebp+var_1C], 0
.text:005AE57F                 jmp     short loc_5AE58A
```

It has a lot of vars, from `var_548` descending 4 by 4 until what you can see on the image.

Now I know that this is supposed to be a function that looks like this:

```
void __cdecl sub_5DE260(STRUCT *lpInfo, int a1, int a2, int a3)
```

(I know this because someone else posted it on a forum)

Now, here are my doubts (sorry if it's dumb), why does the function have 4 arguments? (I only see 2 `arg_` in there, shouldn't be 2 then?) I have one idea of why this could be.. but I'm not sure.. I see that with vars it's going down 4 by 4, and the args are `_0` and `_C` which means if it's 4 by 4 too, then there would be 2 more args in between.. but I don't really know.

And the second question, how can you know that the first argument is a structure? My only idea here is that it has something to do with that "Alpha" there. I would ask how to get that struct too, but that's probably harded, so I want to understand the more basic part first. :)

---

Edit: Sorry for adding an image, I copied the text instead now.

There's 2 calls to this function, I'll add both of the now:

```
loc_4F1058:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_4F0E29+219j
.text:004F1058                 push    0
.text:004F105A                 push    0
.text:004F105C                 mov     ecx, [ebp+var_64]
.text:004F105F                 mov     edx, [ecx]
.text:004F1061                 mov     ecx, [ebp+var_64]
.text:004F1064                 call    dword ptr [edx+18h]
.text:004F1067
.text:004F1067 loc_4F1067:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_4F0E29+206j
.text:004F1067                                         ; sub_4F0E29+22Dj
.text:004F1067                 cmp     [ebp+var_60], 0
.text:004F106B                 jz      short loc_4F1083
.text:004F106D                 push    0
.text:004F106F                 mov     eax, [ebp+arg_8]
.text:004F1072                 push    eax
.text:004F1073                 mov     cl, [ebp+var_38]
.text:004F1076                 push    ecx
.text:004F1077                 mov     edx, [ebp+arg_4]
.text:004F107A                 push    edx
.text:004F107B                 call    sub_5AE50B
.text:004F1080                 add     esp, 10h
.text:004F1083
.text:004F1083 loc_4F1083:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_4F0E29+242j
.text:004F1083                 jmp     short loc_4F109B
```

The other one looks like this:

```
loc_5B81CF:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_5B81A9+22j
.text:005B81CF                 mov     ecx, [ebp+arg_C]
.text:005B81D2                 push    ecx
.text:005B81D3                 mov     edx, [ebp+arg_8]
.text:005B81D6                 push    edx
.text:005B81D7                 mov     al, [ebp+arg_4]
.text:005B81DA                 push    eax
.text:005B81DB                 mov     ecx, [ebp+arg_0]
.text:005B81DE                 push    ecx
.text:005B81DF                 call    sub_5AE50B
.text:005B81E4                 add     esp, 10h
.text:005B81E7
.text:005B81E7 loc_5B81E7:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_5B81A9+24j
.text:005B81E7                 pop     ebp
.text:005B81E8                 retn
.text:005B81E8 sub_5B81A9      endp
```

Does that help?
I still don't know how to use the function, 'cause I don't understand what the arguments should look like.. this guy on the forum posted the function I wrote above, but that had a struct that I don't know.

Comment: It would help if the `call` instruction shows in the disassembly to be sure of what is being set up for the call.  (Or is this the called function itself; hard to say as you aren't showing addresses.)

Comment: Impossible to say since you haven't shown the entire function.  Also don't post images, cut & paste the disassembled code.

Comment: @OP: The C signature with `STRUCT *lpInfo` shows a *pointer to* a struct, not a struct arg.  If the arg *was* a struct passed by value, it would potentially be larger than 4 bytes, and (in at least some 32-bit x86 calling conventions) be copied onto the stack by the caller, rather than passed by reference.  Speaking of calling conventions, we can rule out `__fastcall` as an explanation for only 2 named stack args, unless the first register arg is unused because the function writes ECX without reading it first.  So no register args; `gcc -mregparm=2` can also be ruled out from clobbering EAX.

Comment: I've edited the first post, replaced the image and added 2 calls to the function.

Answer (score 2):

We don't have enough evidence from the snippet you posted to tell if `mov ecx, [eax+30h]` is an array or struct access.  So from what you show, the first arg could be `int *arg_0`.

**The fact that there is an arg at `ebp+14h`**, with a gap of 8 bytes from the end of the pointer first arg at `ebp+8`, tells us that either

- the first arg is actually a by-value struct that takes up 12 bytes
- the disassembly is incomplete and didn't see the code that does use the middle args
- there are 4 dword-sized args, but the middle two are unused.  (Or there's one unused `double` arg).  Actually, normal calling conventions require arg padded to fill a dword stack slot, so we can't rule out stuff like the middle args having `char`, `float`, `short`, or `void*` type either.  No reason to assume they're `int`.

  **In fact, the callers are doing `mov al, stuff` / `push eax`, so it looks like one of the unused args *is* a `char` or `uint8_t`.**

---

**If `[ebp+14h]` wasn't an arg, then the code would be reading stack memory owned by its caller, and that wouldn't make sense.**

`cmp     [ebp+arg_C], 0Ah` / `jnz     loc_5AE7C9` jumps if the dword arg is != 10.  I was thinking at first that it was probably actually a `char` arg (and checking for a newline), but IDA omits an operand-size and the only thing that implies a size is the `arg_C` which is defined as a `dword ptr`.  So maybe it's a character passed in an `int`, or it's checking for `10` for some other reason.

Comment: Hi! So if arguments are not being used, they are not shown? That's good to know. The function is being called in 2 places, I added both on the original post. Does that help to establish a bit more info?

Comment: @user1913644: I don't use IDA, but yeah it appears that way.  There's no way for it to decide whether it's one 8-byte arg vs. two 4-byte args, or two `char` args padded to 4-byte stack slots, so it makes perfect sense for it to not show anything.

Comment: I made it work with int *a, 2 non used in the middle and then int d on the end. Don't know what the 2 in the middle are yet, one of them does work with either int or char, both cases are just null or 0 though when hooked.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get familiar with the concept of [*calling convention* (CC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).
The CC will tell you how many parameters a function takes.

Handwritten assembly functions may not adhere to any existing standard CC thereby making each function have its own CC.
In that case, a full reverse engineering of the function is required, along with the one of the context surrounding the calling sites.

Since there is a [SEH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft-specific_exception_handling_mechanisms) handler in the accused function, you are under Windows.

In Windows the prominent CC are:

- stdcall
- cdecl
- borland
- thiscall

If you look at the call sites and make the assumption that the function doesn't unbalance the stack, you see that the four DWORDs pushed on the stack *immediately before* the call will be lost *immediately after the call* (due to the `add esp, 10h` instruction).
If the function were not to use them, that'd be a pointless operation. 
In fact, while a lot of malware are made up of numerous long sequences of instruction that turn out to do nothing, this pattern is the textbook signature of the *cdecl* convention.

It could also have been the *thiscall* or the *fastcall* but luckily we see that `ecx` is loaded *and* pushed, so it's not an argument on its own (like these two CCs require).
Same goes for the *borland* CC.

Since in the *cdecl* is the caller that cleans the stack, the `add esp, 10h` tells us that 10h / 4 = 4 arguments are used.

---

IDA does its best but, in my experience, it's not an automatic tool.

If you RE just the first part of the function:

```
                              push    ebp
.text:005AE50C                 mov     ebp, esp                    ;Prolog

.text:005AE50E                 push    0FFFFFFFFh
.text:005AE510                 push    offset loc_876BAE           ;Watch this, SEH handlers can be used to escape a debugger
.text:005AE515                 mov     eax, large fs:0
.text:005AE51B                 push    eax
.text:005AE51C                 mov     large fs:0, esp             ;Set SEH handler

.text:005AE523                 sub     esp, 524h                   ;Allocated 524h bytes of stack

.text:005AE529                 mov     eax, [ebp+arg_0]
.text:005AE52C                 mov     ecx, [eax+30h]              ;Common pattern: load a value and access an offset
                                                                   ;this usually is: array (rare, the are iterated),
                                                                   ;struct (possible) or C++ vtable (very likely considering the
                                                                   ;code around the call site)
```

You see the common pattern where a register is loaded with a value from memory (`mov eax, [ebp+arg_0]`) and then it is used as an indirect access (`mov ecx, [eax+30h]`).
This is a pointer access.

As I commented, it's possible that `arg_0` is an array but it seldom happen that code needs to access a random element in an array, you mostly see arrays used in loops.
It could be a struct or it could be a C++ class (that, vtable apart, are the same thing at this level).

Considering this code present at one of the call site:

```
.text:004F1058                 push    0
.text:004F105A                 push    0
.text:004F105C                 mov     ecx, [ebp+var_64]
.text:004F105F                 mov     edx, [ecx]
.text:004F1061                 mov     ecx, [ebp+var_64]
.text:004F1064                 call    dword ptr [edx+18h]
```

where:

- An indirect call is made through an offsetted register (`[edx+18h`])
- `ecx` is loaded just before the call (Hint: the double loading of `ecx` means this was compiled with optimizations out).

We can *speculate* that that's a *fastcall* to a C++ member function, thus is likely that the program is a C++ one and hence the arg is a class.

However we cannot tell for sure with the limited sample, it could be a struct in a C++ program or that call could be a COM call.

The `alpha` thing found by IDA is not related to `arg_0` since it is an offset to `ebp`, thus a local var.